# Select a file in the default file explorer

Tags: c++, linux, qt, unix

I found out that (on at least debian) the command to display a directory with the default file explorer is `gvfs-open <dir path>`. It works fine but I want a file inside that directory to be selected.

In Qt I can open a directory with the default file explorer like this :

```
QDir dir = QFileInfo(filepath).absoluteDir(); //get the directory
QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl( "file:///" + dir.absolutePath() ) ); //open it
```

Same as `gvfs-open <dir path>`.

If I use it like this it will open the default application to open the file instead of selecting it inside that directory :

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl( "file:///" + filepath ) );
```

But how do I **select** a file in the default file explorer? I want to open the directory and select that file from `filepath`. Or is that not possible?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3363/how-to-open-a-nautilus-directory-and-select-a-file-in-it-from-the-command-line

Comment: Have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/3546503/1578528