# QT: Launch default exporer on a directory selecting a file

Tags: c++, qt

My application displays a grid of images. When the right mouse button is clicked a context menu is displayed where the first option is "Show in Explorer".

I was able to launch the default explorer on the directory by using:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile( directory ));
```

However I want also the file to be selected.

Is this possible? I suppose it should be, as many apps can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I want to thank @Chernobyl for his useful help.

However I've found a general solution posted here:
[How to "Reveal in Finder" or "Show in Explorer" with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490336/how-to-reveal-in-finder-or-show-in-explorer-with-qt)

It wasn't compiling at first because the QtCreator code is using a class called Environment which I tried to add to my project but that file then also includes others, etc. I checked and they are using it just to see if explorer.exe can be found on the system path. It was not so important (to me) so I removed that check and then I tested it. It's working perfectly. It's also supposed to work for Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

`openUrl` is not suitable here. You need just start another process (with `QProcess` `start` or `startDetached`) with Windows explorer special arguments:

`explorer.exe /select,"C:\pathTo\file.txt"`

Comment: Thanks, but what happens if the user is on a Mac or Linux?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson  I thought that you need Windows approach. Probably there is no easy cross-platform way to do this. On Windows it is explorer, on ubuntu it can be dolphin or nautilus or something else.

Comment: Ok Chernobyl, thanks, Will research for Mac specially what I need to do.

Comment: BTW, I'm not able to make it work on windows yet. I've used this:  QProcess::startDetached("explorer.exe", QStringList() << "/select" << "\"" + filePath + "\"");  but it's opening the My Documents folder.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457 it seems that you forgot about comma , Also I didn't work with Mac so I coouldn't find same command for Finder.